# Weblogic 12.2.1 Application server JDK 11 support

Tags: weblogic, java-11, application-server

Creating a new domain in Weblogic 12.2.1 server with Oracle JDK 11 fails

What we have tried:

As JDK 8 is already in End of life,
We have upgraded our java servlet based web application to compile with JDK 11.
Tried to deploy in Tomcat 9, it is working fine.

To deploy the same war in WebLogic, When we try to create a new domain in Weblogic 12.2.1 server with Oracle JDK 11, it fails with the below error.

[Weblogic Error while creating new domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aApfd.jpg)

Comment: Java 8 is not yet end-of-life, it is just end-of-public updates. See also Oracle's [Java SE support roadmap](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html). If you pay Oracle (or another Java vendor), or use an open source variant like adoptopenjdk.net, then you can still use Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

WebLogic Server 12c does not support and does not run under Java >= 9. You will have to wait for next major release in 2020.
Check the [Certification Matrix](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/fusion-middleware/documentation/fmw-1221certmatrix-2739738.xlsx) for details.

Answer (score 2):

[WebLogic Server 14c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/standalone/weblogic-server/14.1.1.0/sysrs/system-requirements-and-specifications.html#GUID-A077A2B4-5967-42E0-A063-0F7A0A2254FB) (14.1.1.0.0) supports JDK 11.
WebLogic Server 12.2.1.4 supports Oracle JDK 8 and Oracle JDK 11

Comment: I do not find this support in the doc you linked nor in the certification documentation https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/fusion-certification.html

Comment: @MarianoPaniga, Check under the section "Java Development Kit (JDK) Requirements"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I found the section in the document, but since it was in contrast with the certification matrix (which is considered the official reference), I posted an explicit answer on this and a community leader replied JDK is not supported/certified:
https://community.oracle.com/mosc/discussion/4477276/conflicting-documentation-regarding-jdk11-support-for-weblogic14c#latest
I hope the official certification will be added soon.